# Uncheck the checkBox when Cancel button is clicked

Tags: angularjs

```
    <th><input type="checkBox" id="acceptAll" ng-model="view.show" ng-click="$ctrl.selectAll(branchAccess, view.show)> All </th>

    <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel(branchAccess, view.show)">Cancel </button>


    In controller
    --------------

   this.view={};
   this.view.show=false;

    this.cancel = function(branchAccess, checkStatus){
      checkstatus= false;
      this.view.show=false;
    };
```

//i haave made above variables true and false, and changed vice versa;

All i want is that on clicking cancel buton should uncheck the checkBox;

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D All the documentation and examples you need.

Comment: You're passing `view.show` as a second parameter, so change `ng-click="$ctrl.cancel(branchAccess, view.show)"` to `ng-click="$ctrl.cancel(branchAccess, view)"` in the function change `this.view.show=false;` to `checkStatus.show = false`

Comment: Awesome, It worked; could you explain why the way I did did not work?

Comment: How do i accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your references are inconsistent. In your controller, you're attaching `view` to the controller, but in the template you're referring to it as if it were on `$scope`.

Change the references to `view.show` in the template to `$ctrl.view.show`